# How to pass variable to jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, url

I'm trying to validate if an url is valid, but I have variables that are not present in my form, how can I validate if that variable is valid?

I tried to use some solutions for other questions, but it does not work with some links (I think due to the japanese language)

for example

```
https://www.google.com.bo/maps/place/GRILL+DINING+%26+WINE+%E9%87%91%E5%B1%B1%E3%83%86%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9/@35.1434789,136.9007332,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x600370ad2c5a420d:0x8c45fe9535e051bc!4m14!1m8!3m7!1s0x6003717984d38b7f:0x263a2351ccce747a!2zSmFww7NuLCBQcmVmZWN0dXJhIGRlIEFpY2hpTmFnb3lhTmFrYSBXYXJkLCBLYW5heWFtYSwgNCBDaG9tZeKIkjYsIOWQjeWPpOWxi-mHkeWxseODm-ODhuODqyAxMOmajiBHUklMTCBESU5JTkcgJiBXSU5FIOmHkeWxseODhuODqeOCuQ!8m2!3d35.1434745!4d136.9029219!11m1!2e1!3m4!1s0x6003717984d38b7f:0x263a2351ccce747a!8m2!3d35.1434745!4d136.9029219?hl=en&authuser=0
```

Comment: Check the documentation of your validation plugin how it works and how it has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

finally, this works :)

```
        function checkUrlIsValid(urlString){
            let regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
            let check = regexp.test(urlString);
            if (check === true){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```